# What Should be the basic flow of AWS API Gateway Integration in React JS with cognito user pool authentication system?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am using React JS in frontend and AWS Server less architecture as the backend of the react application.
So, for the user authentication and authorization I am using the AWS Cognito Service. and for making the requests I am using the axios.

Now, I want to integrate APIs which are created with the AWS API Gateway with cognito user pool. I am able to sign in to the user session and retrieving the id Token, access Token, and Refresh Token. and I am sending the ID Token in the all request which are created with AWS API Gateway. But How can I know that token is expired? because when token is expired it is sending the Network error instead of message("Token is Expired.").

In short I want to handle situation if token is expired or token is invalid. what I have to do?
Give the basic flow of handling the all requests(GET, POST, etc...) using axios.